# Remove whitespace after a particular symbol

Tags: javascript

I've got a string which has the `>` symbol multiple times. After every `>` symbol there is a line break. How can I remove whitespaces after every `>` symbol in the string?

This is what I tried for spaces. But I need to remove whitespaces only after `>` symbol.

```
str.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

String:

```
<Apple is red>
<Grapes - Purple>
<Strawberries are Red>
```

Comment: can you please share the string?

Comment: Are you trying to remove space character or newline character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to remove newline characters you can use `RegExp` `/(>)(\n)/g` to replace second capture group `(\n)` with replacement empty string `""`

```js
var str = `<Apple is red>
<Grapes - Purple>
<Strawberries are Red>`;

console.log(`str:${str}`);
var res = str.replace(/(>)(\n)/g, "$1");
console.log(`res:${res}`);
```

Comment: Thanks. There is no space. It's only a linebreak. See my edit for an example.

Comment: Are you trying to remove line break?

Comment: As in my edit. I want the output to be like this:
`<Apple is red><Grapes - Purple><Strawberries are Red>`

Comment: @Becky Yes. Have you tried `javascript` at updated post? Will include a stacksnippets

Comment: What does `${ }` mean? ( ${str} )

Comment: @Becky See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38908097/javascript-template-example/

Comment: Is it possible to print the string in to a div?

Comment: like document.getElementById('output').innerText = res:${res}; I tried that but does not show the trimmed text.

Comment: @Becky Yes, it should be possible.  Though this is not present Question? Have you read linked Question/Answer? Note the "``" characters at Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
str.replace(/>\s/g, '>')
```

Demo:

```js
console.log(`<Apple is red>
<Grapes - Purple>
<Strawberries are Red>`.replace(/>\s/g, '>'))
```

Comment: I think `(>\s*)` would be more appropriate.As it would match all whitespaces afeter the `>`

Comment: @Rambler The OP's string contains only one whitespace after the `>`.

Comment: @Gothdo Thanks. There's line breaks after `>` and no spaces. See my edit for an exmaple.

Comment: Looks good. But what's the difference between your answer and `RomanPerekhrest`'s answer?

Comment: @Becky RomanPerekhrest's answer matches multiple whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach:

```js
var str = 'some>  text >    the end>',
    replaced = str.replace(/(\>)\s+/g, "$1");

console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: Whats the difference between you answer and `Gothdo`'s answer?

Comment: @Becky, you're strange. You said *Looks good* at first, then - you've change your mind

Answer (score 0):

1. You must use /m flag on your regex pattern
2. You must use $1 capture group symbol on your replacement text

   ```
   var text = '<Apple is red>\r\n<Grapes - Purple>\r\n<Strawberries are Red>';
   var regex = /(>)\s*[\n]/gm;
   var strippedText = text.replace(regex,'$1');
   ```

Comment: Thanks. What's the difference between `(/(>)(\n)/g)` and `/(>)\s*[\n]/gm` ?

Comment: I've updated, my suggested regex. /gm is suport global and multiline search.